# Where to set unsafe mode in Safari 10 to made java plugin access local file

Tags: safari, applet, mode, unsafe, beta

I just updated my Safari from Safari 9 to safari 10 beta version.
My client is a java applet runs from a page. In Safari 9 and before version, it runs OK. But in Safari 10 beta, it fails.
I found that safari 10 blocks access to local files from Java applet.
So I think it is because the java plugin runs under safe mode.
But in Safari ->preferences->security->Plug-in Settings. 
there is no unsafe mode option to check. there is only three option :Ask,Off,On.
So my client can not access local file in safe mode now.

My mac system is OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6
and Safari version is version 10.0

Is that possible to set Unsafe mode in Safari 10 beta version?

Answer (score 10):

In safari 10 beta,safari->preferences->security->Plug-in Settings, Press option key on your keyboard and click the three option(Ask,Off,On), you can see additional options in addition to the Ask,Off,On. Un-check the "Run In Safe Mode" and it run the same as the unsafe mode in older version.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works. Where did you find it? 
it's hide if you do not press option key.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I had the same issue and I found this by guessing, not even mentioned in any document/ on the internet..........