# Applet doesn't work in OS 10.13

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

i was doing this tutorial from my book, which consists in using this applet in the web browser, it works in eclipse but it doesn't in safari,
The code looks like this:

```
package applet;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.*;

public class NotHelloWorld extends JApplet
{

    public void init()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->
        {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("not hello world applet",
                    SwingConstants.CENTER);
            add(label);
        });
    }

}
```

And the html file in the same folder with the jar file above is

```
<applet class=“applet/NotHelloWorld.class” archive=“NotHelloWorld.jar” width=“300” height=“300></applet>
```

When i open the html file made with textnote I just see the code you see above not the applet. 
I tried to install the last version of java, restart the browser,activate java in safari but nothing seems to work, any help?

Comment: Does IOS still support the <applet/> tag? Applets have been in disuse for a while.

Comment: I don't know tbh, I'm new to this thing.. should i move on? I was just following the book

Comment: For learning, it might be ok. But for production stuff, the world has moved on.

Comment: applets are dead, for a very long time. If your book still teaches applets, then it's a very old, or a bad book. You might want to learn from another book.

Comment: Well, the book is "core java", I don't think is that bad but the version was printed in 2016

Comment: Ok the author says in the introduction to applet that the reading is just for interest indeed, I hadn't read it before

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate, or at least it'll help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38820369/6505250

Comment: *"..should i move on?"* I cannot stress enough.. ***yes.*** See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).